# What does the yellow highlight on filename mean in the projects tab in Intellij?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ide

**I've googled it and cant figure it out and its lowkey annoying and how can I remove it.[image]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is python's vendor directory used to install python executables and python libraries.

Let's assume that you do not have panda library in your venv.
IntelliJ ide's smart context action will propose you to `install package panda` library. That library will be installed in your venv directory.

```
import panda
```

---

In the Project View, you can uncheck `show excluded files`. This will hide all excluded files. venv is one of them.

Project View's > Settings Icon > Tree Apperance > Show Excluded Files.

But if you want only change that glowing highlighted color. Go to
`IntelliJ > Preferences or Settings > File Colors > Non-Project Files` 
You can tweak the color or disable all colors in project view by unchecking `Use in project view`

Hope, it helps.

Comment: thank you for explaining that well and is there a way I can unhighlight it?